# Java Discord Api Moving users

Tags: java, discord

I'm busy with an discord bot with the Java Discord Api.

I'm kinda stuck between if it doesn't work or its an bug. I want to move people to a voice channel. But somewhere the code doesn't go any further and doesn't return an exception or an break event from the compiler / ide.

```
@Override
public boolean called(String[] args, MessageReceivedEvent event)
{
    if(args.length < 2 || event.getMessage().getMentionedUsers().size() < 1 || Permissions.GetPermissions(event) == 0)
    {
        System.out.print("you dont have the permissions");
        return false;
    }

    boolean channelexists = false;
    boolean userexists = false;

    for(VoiceChannel channel : event.getGuild().getVoiceChannels())
    {
        if(channel.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(args[1]))
        {
            System.out.print("found ---> " + channel.getName() + "\n");
            channelexists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(VoiceChannel channel : event.getGuild().getVoiceChannels())
    {
        if(channel.getMembers().contains(event.getMessage().getMentionedUsers().get(0)))
        {
            System.out.print("found ---> " + channel.getMembers().contains(event.getMessage().getMentionedUsers().get(0).getName()) + "\n");
            userexists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return channelexists && userexists;
}

@Override
public void action(String[] args, MessageReceivedEvent event) 
{
    GuildController controller = new GuildController(event.getGuild());
    VoiceChannel voicechannel = null;

    for(VoiceChannel channel : event.getGuild().getVoiceChannels())
    {
        if(channel.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(args[1]))
        {
            voicechannel = channel;
            break;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        controller.moveVoiceMember((Member) event.getMessage().getMentionedUsers().get(0), voicechannel);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the line with the containing print line doesnt seems to trigger.

```
System.out.print("found ---> " + channel.getMembers().contains(event.getMessage().getMentionedUsers().get(0).getName()) + "\n");
```

but when i debug like this

```
System.out.print(channel.getMembers().contains(event.getMessage().getMentionedUsers().get(0)));
```

the console writes false. and even when im in one of the channels.

so im kinda bothering if its an bug or im just stupid.

thx for helping and regards from me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.print(channel.getMembers().contains(event.getMessage().getMentionedUsers().get(0)));
```

> the console writes false.

Same value is used as the condition within your `if` control and since the `if` condition evaluates to `false`, it's obvious that the block within the `if`(in your query the print line) wouldn't be executed. Hence the line with the containing print line doesn't seem to trigger.

Take a look at [`If` - Nuts and Bolts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)